# How do I combine the menu items inside the swicth case in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, switch-statement, .net-framework-version

- I have several menu items under the `View` menu in my parent form, each one of these menu items opens a child form.
- I can call the child forms with a separate method for each menu item, but I want to combine all the menu items inside a switch case.
- How do I do that?

[image: Menu Image]

Separate event method for each child:

```
private void child1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(Application.OpenForms["Child1"] is Child1 ch1)
  {
    ch1.Focus();
    return;
  }
  ch1= new Child1();
  ch1.Name = name1; //name assigned in parent form
  ch1.Age = age1; // age assigned in parent form;
}
```

I have written the following code to combine the menu inside the switch statement, it isn't showing any error but does not display the child form either.

```
private void viewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ToolStripMenuItem menu = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
            
   switch(menu.Name)
            {
                case "Child1":
                    if(Application.OpenForms["Child1"] is Child1 ch1)
                    {
                        ch1.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                    ch1= new Child1();
                    ch1.Name = name1; //name assigned in parent form
                    ch1.Age = age1; // age assigned in parent form;
                    ch1.show();
                    break;
                case "Child2":
                    if (Application.OpenForms["Child2"] is Child2 ch2)
                    {
                        ch2.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                    ch2 = new Child2();
                    ch2.Name = name2; //name2 assigned in parent form
                    ch2.Age = age2; // age2 assigned in parent form;
                    ch2.show();
                    break;

                case "Child3":
                    if (Application.OpenForms["Child3"] is Child3 ch3)
                    {
                        ch3.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                    ch3 = new Child3();
                    ch3.Name = name3; //name3 assigned in parent form
                    ch3.Age = age3; // age3 assigned in parent form
                    ch3.show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I solved it, if anyone is looking for the same problem, the solution is in the **Parent.Designer.cs** window where you find auto-generated code for the controls.

```
this.chil1ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "chil1ToolStripMenuItem"
```

so the `menu.name` in **Parent.cs** should be the same as the one above name or you can edit the `this.chil1ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "chil1ToolStripMenuItem"` to

`this.chil1ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "chil1Menu"`